# Type of hanger on hanging beam?

Tags: walls, load-bearing, load

I am putting in a hanging beam in my ranch style house. To replace a load bearing center wall. The only load on the wall is ceiling load. It is a hip roof. The lumber in all rough cut. They are 2x6 ceiling joist that are spliced on top of the wall. So I need a hanger 4"x at least 12" tall. I can't find any hangers like this. Or could I use long hurricane ties?

Comment: You're asking major questions with no information... how about a few pictures??

Comment: Ceiling load might not seem like much, but depending on weather - wind/hurricanes that try to tear off the roof or snow that weighs down the roof, it can be quite a bit. Location (country/state/region) may be relevant.

Comment: I don't have any pictures right now. The house is 32'x40'. The ceiling joists run the 32' way. 16" in on center. Ceiling joist. I am using 2- 2x12 LVLs. That will be set above the ceiling joist for a hanging beam. I have to connect the 2x6 ceiling joist to the beam with some type of hanger. Just don't know which type?

Comment: It's in Michigan. 30 psf snow load. It's an interior wall. So there is no roof load. Just the ceiling joists and plaster load.

Comment: Are those 2x6 ceiling joists part of a truss? We need a pic. Click on the icon in your question to add a pic.

Comment: Hard to tell from your description what you need.  Do you have a sketch or a picture?  Have you looked through the Simpson catalogue?

Comment: The 2x6 and not part of a truss. It is a rafter hip roof with rough cut lumber. No vertical supports in attic. The 2x6 ceiling joist go from exterior wall to exterior wall and sit on interior wall where there is a splice in center. I want to put a beam above ceiling joist and hang them in attic. Then remove the wall. I know the beam size for the load. Just can't find a hanger that will take 4 inch wide joist. I don't have a picture.

Comment: If you don't have nor can you take a picture, how about a sketch? Doesn't have to be a CAD drawing to mm scale, just a neatly done sketch showing the major pieces and with dimensions labeled (not even to scale). It seems that each time someone asks you for more info, you give another little dribble, then get frustrated that someone asks for more. Please remember that you're getting free help for what you should probably be paying a structural engineer to do for you, so please do your best to help us help you.

Answer (score -1):

I’ve never seen a hanger with those design requirements. I like the idea of using a hanger that allows the joists to “sit” in a hanger’s pocket rather than using straps to tie the joists up to the beam. However.....

However, installing such a hanger under joists without damaging the drywall, would be difficult.

I’d try a strap such as Simpson’s HTSQ twist strap.

https://www.strongtie.com/twiststraps_specialtystraps/htsq_strap/p/htsq.

If the joists span half the width of the building (16’) and only supports a ceiling load, then the load on each joists is:

Joists = 2 psf (per square foot)

Plaster = 8-10 psf (depending on type)

Total load = 12 psf x 16’ x 1.33 (to get to 16” oc)

For a total load on each joist = 255 lbs. / 2 (to get load at each end = 128 lbs.

As you can see, these straps are rated up to 720 lbs. depending on the species and grade for uplift. (Your resistance is the reverse of uplift, but is the same principle, but  upside down. )

Now, the shortest strap is 16” long, which means 8” should be on each member. However, your joists are 6” tall so they won’t have the intended “cover”. But, your load is so much smaller than the maximum the straps could support, that I’m sure they’ll be fine.

You also have one more issue: If your new beam deflects (sags) at all, then the joists will sag and the ceiling will crack. Plaster is notorious for cracking with minimal deflection.

I have not allowed weight for anything in the attic, (like insulation, light fixtures, etc.)

Comment: I planed on using  2- 2x14 lvls. They have a load of 254 for L/360 per beam. I figured it should be about 1/4 inch of deflection across the 16'. I also used 20PSF as my load.  Thanks